# Can you layout above the StatusBar in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Currently I'm trying to build an in app notification which slides in from the top of the screen. My goal is to have this element above the status bar of my app.

I have already tried to fix this by using `zIndex: 9999999` and `position: 'absolute'` but nothing seems to be working.

Is it even possible to render nodes above the `StatusBar` Component?

[image: Problem explained visual]

example code:

```
<View>
  <View style={style.notification}>
    <Avatar />
    <Text>Notification Title</Text>
    <Text>Notification body</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [setHidden](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#sethidden) method?

Comment: Yes but this seems a bit hacky for what I'm after. I'd rather have layout on top of the StatusBar.